# SVN: too many revisions. is there are faster way than `blame` to get the latest committer on a specific line?

Tags: svn

I want to find who made the latest change to a few lines on a file. svn blame is way to slow, I didn't have the patience to wait it out. The file in question is also very large. Can I just check the blame for a fraction of the file (a few lines) if that would make things faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell blame to only consider some subset of the revisions in your project to speed things along to some extent. Especially if you know the line changed sometime after a certain date or revision. Do this with the `-r` flag just like most of the other svn commands.

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work in what situation? I'm not aware of any special cases for the blame tool.

Comment: I meant if you want the latest revisions only, basically default behavior or blame.

Comment: I'm still not following you. You can pass a range like `1234:HEAD` for all revisions since 1234, or `{2014-10-01}:HEAD` for all revisions since October 2014. Were you trying to do something different? As I mentioned, I don't think there's a way to limit the line range of the command.